# How can I execute wake command in some github repo?

Tags: json, github

In some repositories like [soc-freedom-sifive](https://github.com/sifive/soc-freedom-sifive) in github, I found that I have to execute `wake` command to use the code.

`wake --init .`

`wake -v compileScalaModule e300ScalaModule`

But I have searched the command on the internet and got nothing useful. I guess it may be related to JS due to a json file in the repo. Now I'm confused. How can I find some manual about `wake` command to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some Googling, and it looks like `wake` refers to the SiFive wake build tool:

https://github.com/sifive/wake

If this is the right answer, given that it was hard for you and me to figure out, one might consider opening a pull request on the soc-freedom-sifive README explaining the dependency.